# How to set initial zoom on UIWebView in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pdf, uiwebview

I'm wondering how to set an initial zoom on a PDF document loaded in a UIWebView in XCode. It is a table, and I want the web view to load zoomed in on a specific column (or part of a column which I can then scroll up and down). I've been reading and some people have pointed to this method `- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script` but I don't know exactly how this works.

And while we're on the subject of PDFs, is there any way to scrape the PDF and turn it into usable strings?

**Edit:** For reading a pdf, PDFBox is one possible solution. You have to import JAR files into your Xcode project. Here is a tutorial: http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/mac/2005/01/07/ipod_reader.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UIWebView *webV = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
webV.scrollView.zoomScale = 4.0;
```

Comment: [best one found](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8143786/3577656) try adding meta tag in your html page,in your <head> tag.It gets repaired in a eye blink. 
Try the [apple link](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html) and select the suitable meta tag for you.